# Gradle: Use BuildScript RepositoryHandler as Project Repository Handler

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm implementing a custom plugin and inside this plugin I am providing a default repository configuration like so:

```
class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

  ...
  ...
  ...

  @Override
  void apply(Project project) {

    project.repositories {
      mavenLocal()
      mavenCentral()
      jcenter()
    }

    ...
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

However, in order to be able to apply my plugin inside a build script, the client code will have a add a section like this in their build script anyway:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
      mavenLocal()
      maven { url "<organization maven repo url>" }
      mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.organization.xxx:my-plugin:1.0.130'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.organization.my-plugin'
```

Given, that, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

  ...
  ...
  ...

  @Override
  void apply(Project project) {

    project.repositories = project.buildscript.repositories

    ...
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

But, when I do that, I get an error, understandably, as the `project.repositories` property is read-only.

So, is there a proper way I could achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error is because you are trying to assign a value to the property `project.repositories`. Fortunately, you just need to *add* repositories, so maybe this will work (untested)

```
@Override
void apply(Project project) {
  project.repositories.addAll(project.buildscript.repositories)
}
```

<sub>By the way, I'm not sure you really want to do this. Better would be to define common repositories somewhere else and then maybe add to both buildscript and project</sub>

Comment: Yeah, I was getting the error because the project.repositories property is read-only.

Your solution worked perfectly!

But, I do see concerns about the idea and I wish I could store them in a common place. However, the I'm trying to pull-in the buildscript repositories declared by the client code and so I don't know what they will be ahead of time.

Comment: BTW, just out of curiosity, do you know if I can totally override the default configuration from my build script?

For example, now, when I declare another 'repositories' section in my 'client' build script, the new repositories seem to be added to the default list provided by the plugin. Anyway I could completely overwrite that list?

Comment: Don't know. Try the Groovydoc of RepositoryHandler: if it has a remove() or clear() method then you definitely can

Comment: I was looking there and it doens't. So maybe not. :(